# WPF: can't set ItemsPresenter to use a VirtualizingStackPanel

Tags: wpf

I've seen a few posts about this, including on StackOverflow - but I can't find an answer.

In WPF, I created a `ControlTemplate` for a `ComboBox`, simply by clicking "Edit Template -> Copy" in visual studio.

Now my problem is that the items in the dropdown are presented in an `ItemsPresenter`, and I simply can't figure out how to use a `VirtualizingStackPanel` inside that `ItemsPresenter`. I tried settings the `ItemsPanel` of the control in the control's style, but that doesn't help.

Here is the XAML of the `ControlTemplate`. It is pretty standard. The `ItemsPresenter` is called PART_ItemsPresenter.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}"
                              Width="0" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Popup
            x:Name="PART_Popup"
            AllowsTransparency="True"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
            PopupAnimation="Fade"
            Placement="Bottom">
            <!--<themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="shadow" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=templateRoot}">-->
            <Border
                x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"
                MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=templateRoot}">
                <ScrollViewer
                    x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                    <Grid x:Name="grid" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                        <Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                Width="0">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"
                                       Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"
                                       Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" />
                        </Canvas>
                        <ItemsPresenter
                            x:Name="PART_ItemsPresenter"
                            KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                        </ItemsPresenter>
                    </Grid>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
            <!--</themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>-->
        </Popup>
        <ToggleButton
            x:Name="toggleButton"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
            <ToggleButton.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
                    <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                        Background="{StaticResource ControlBackgroundBrush}"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <Border x:Name="splitBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                            BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,-1,-1,-1"
                                            Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                                        <Path
                                            x:Name="Arrow"
                                            Data="M0,0C0,0 3.5,4 3.5,4 3.5,4 7,0 7,0 7,0 0,0 0,0z"
                                            Fill="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                    </Border>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot"
                                                Value="{StaticResource ControlBackgroundMouseOverBrush}" />
                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot"
                                                Value="{StaticResource ControlBorderMouseOverBrush}" />
                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder"
                                                Value="{StaticResource ControlBorderMouseOverBrush}" />
                                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow"
                                                Value="{StaticResource ControlBorderMouseOverBrush}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FFC4E5F6" />
                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF2C628B" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FFF4F4F4" />
                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FFADB2B5" />
                                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="#FFF4F4F4" />
                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="#FFADB2B5" />
                                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow"
                                                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ToggleButton.Style>
        </ToggleButton>
        <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{StaticResource ControlBackgroundBrush}"
                Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
            <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                     HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                     IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                     Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                     VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                <TextBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
                        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />
                        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst" />
                        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False" />
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                                    <ScrollViewer
                                        x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                                        Template="{Binding PART_ItemsPresenter.Template}"
                                        Background="Transparent"
                                        Focusable="False"
                                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </TextBox.Style>
            </TextBox>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="Border" Value="0.56" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        </Trigger>
        <!--<Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="shadow" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
            <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="shadow" Value="#71000000"/>
        </Trigger>-->
        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="95" />
        </Trigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="True" />
                <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="False" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False" />
        </MultiTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect"
                    Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect"
                    Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Please describe how you test whether it works or not.

Comment: Did you get a chance to review my revised answer?  I reproduced your issue, and it seems that the _name_ of your `ItemsPresenter` is somehow mitigating the virtualization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be all you need in your `ComboBox` style:

```
<Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing"
        Value="True" />
<Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode"
        Value="Recycling" />
<Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <VirtualizingStackPanel
        IsItemsHost="True"
        IsVirtualizing="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                 Path=(VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing)}"
        VirtualizationMode="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                     Path=(VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode)}" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Whether you use the `Standard` or `Recycling` virtualization mode is up to you.  The `Recycling` mode tends to cause some odd artifacts on a `ComboBox`.  For example: as you scroll, you may see more than one item highlighted with the 'selected' effect (but never more than one in view at a time).

However, **there is a catch** to making this work: you need to rename `PART_ItemsPresenter` to something else (I renamed it to `ItemsPresenter`).  I have not been able to nail down *why*, but when you use the name `PART_ItemsPresenter`, <strike>your `ItemsPanelTemplate` doesn't get applied</strike> the virtualization is being negated somehow.  I can see that the template *is* being applied, but there are clearly too many item containers being generated, which makes using a virtualizing panel rather pointless.  Whatever the cause, simply giving your `ItemsPresenter` a different name appears to resolve the issue.

As @mm8 points out, you should also set `MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}"` on `DropDownBorder`, or your popup will try to grow to accommodate all the items.

Lastly, I'm not sure what your intent was when you added the binding below, but you can't just add a named reference to the property path to set the binding source.  Whatever your intent was, this binding is not going to satisfy it.  I'd just get rid of it.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
              Template="{Binding PART_ItemsPresenter.Template}"
              ... />
```

Comment: Thanks. It was the PART_ItemsPresenter that did it - had to change the name.

Comment: Briliant catch by the way. Thank you. How did you figure this out?

Comment: @user884248 I started comparing your custom template to the standard Aero template, singling out any differences I could find to see if they were somehow related.  Changing the items presenter's name felt like an act of desperation, but I'll be damned if it did't work.  I'll update my answer here if I nail down exactly _why_ it makes a difference.

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved me from wasting hours, and possibly days, on this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do multiple things to support virtualization. Setting the `ItemsPanelTemplate` was part of the solution:

```
<Setter Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="True" />
<Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True" />
<Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `ItemsPanel` to a `VirtualizingStackPanel` does work:

```
<Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

However, in order for the actual virtualization to work, you should also set the `MaxHeight` property of the `DropDownBorder` element in your template (or don't comment out the `SystemDropShadowChrome` element):

```
<Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" ...
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually a very smart answer - I never thought about that... unfortunately it doesn't work either :-(

Comment: It certainly works for me. Maybe you should provide a repo of your issue instead of just claiming that it doesn't work. You are obviously doing something wrong. And how to you confirm that it "doesn't work"?